# $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a countable union of disjoint Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reading through Evans's measure theory book and he begins the proof of Lusin's theorem with the following statement:

"For each positive integer $i$, let $(B_{ij})_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be disjoint Borel sets such that $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}} B_{ij}$ and $\operatorname{diam} B_{ij} <\frac{1}{i} $."

I was wondering if, in order to prove this decomposition, one could use the fact that $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}}[p_{r},q_{r}]$, where $p_{r},q_{r}\in\mathbb{Q}$ are such that $q_{r}-p_{r}=1/(n+1)^{i}$, to write $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as the union of closed cubes $A_{ij}$ ($j\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$) with $\operatorname{diam} A_{ij} <\frac{1}{i}$ for all $j$, and lastly, set $B_{i1}=A_{i1}$ and $B_{ij}=A_{ij}-\bigcup_{k=1}^{j-1}A_{ik}$ ($j\geq 2$) to get the disjoint union. Is this correct?